# AWS instance saying DISK IS FULL despite only saving iPython notebooks

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I have an EC2 AWS instance with an attached HD of 30 gigs, and after saving iPython notebooks on it (size ~35k...), it's suddenly telling me it's failing to save because:

```
[W 01:27:33.795 NotebookApp] Unexpected error while saving file: notebook/HW4b.ipynb database or disk is full
[E 01:27:33.795 NotebookApp] {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36",
      "Cookie": "username-ec2-54-166-176-147-compute-1-amazonaws-com-8888=2|1:0|10:1478114370|56:username-ec2-54-166-176-147-compute-1-amazonaws-com-8888|48:NGIxNDk1NWItYzAyOS00MDAwLTk1NDAtYWZhOTFlZWE1ODZk|47f5f026f2d80fd7391876b91613918cf32f693e8e72cb6734f10ab9f903cddd",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "Referer": "https://ec2-54-166-176-147.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8888/notebooks/notebook/HW4b.ipynb",
      "Host": "ec2-54-166-176-147.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8888",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6",
      "Content-Length": "75821",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "Origin": "https://ec2-54-166-176-147.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8888"
```

Comment: What is your question? Did you try logging into the instance to see how much disk space is available? If it is Linux, use the `df-h` command.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, hey John, thanks for the command. It turned out that Tensorflow was recording hundreds of logs of 100+ MB and that's what was taking all the space. We got rid of the record and managed to make it work.

Comment: where did you find those log files